# which function would add a row to another set of rows, so it behaves as if they were below each other?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Example: having data in A1:E4 and another data in G1:K1 and i need to use them to look like A1:E5 so that G1:K1 was added below A1:E4.

The reason behind this is that excel is asking to give set of rows but my rows are not in order (and i can't make them in order). so I'm wondering whether its possible to have a function that would join them together to behave as if they are below each other.

also, can it be possible to add one cell to a column. Example: A1:A5 and i would like to add G1 so it would look like A1:A6.

appreciate your help.

Comment: This depends heavily on the end goal.  Example: if you are trying to add the numbers, `SUM` handles this sort of thing automatically; just feed both ranges to `SUM` as parameters.  If the goal is to use `VLOOKUP` or another function like that, then this is not really possible.

Comment: I believe the answer might be placing +

So the function would look like = A1:E4+G1:K1

To be checked though ?!

Comment: Just call `SUM` then.  It can handle separate ranges.  `=SUM(A1:E4, G1:K1)`